# How to enable _LIBCPP_DEBUG_LEVEL>=2 in xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, clang

When reading the std library implementation I could see lots of checks enabled by `#if _LIBCPP_DEBUG_LEVEL >= 2` conditions. I tried to add `_LIBCPP_DEBUG_LEVEL = 3` in xcode preprocessor options, but `<iterator>` doesn't compile anymore:

```
#if _LIBCPP_DEBUG_LEVEL >= 2
__get_db()->__insert_i(this);   <----- the error is on this line
#endif
```

Is there something else I'm missing here to use a higher debug level for the standard library?

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: Seems like libc++ "Debug Mode" is still not entirely functional in XCode 11.1. I was able to get a library to compile and link with `#define _LIBCPP_DEBUG_LEVEL 2` and
`#define _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR_IF_NODEBUG` in a file (with inconsistent behavior between code in different files) but as soon as I try that in a `main.cpp` or via the XCode Preprocessor Macros setting, I get undefined symbol link errors like to "std::__1::__libcpp_db::__dereferenceable(void const*) const". Were link errors what you had seen or did it not use to get even that far?

Comment: Tried XCode 11.6 now and still have undefined symbols. Discovered though that defining `_LIBCPP_DEBUG=1` alone makes the `__config` include file define `_LIBCPP_DEBUG_LEVEL=2` and setting `_LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR_IF_NODEBUG=` was no longer necessary. That aligns better with the current [LLVM Debug Mode](https://libcxx.llvm.org/docs/DesignDocs/DebugMode.html) document as to how to enable debug mode. Specifically, the `std::__1::__libcpp_db::__insert_c(void*, std::__1::__c_node* (*)(void*, void*, std::__1::__c_node*))` symbol is undefined now if not more.

Comment: Found a related stackoverflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15899937/is-it-possible-to-enable-libcpp-debug2-in-the-current-xcode-4-6-1-toolchain-on

Answer (score 2):

According to the [libc++ documentation](http://libcxx.llvm.org/debug_mode.html):

> Debug mode is currently not functional. Defining _LIBCPP_DEBUG will result in fairly nasty compile errors.

So that is probably the source of that.

Comment: The link to http://libcxx.llvm.org/debug_mode.html doesn't appear to work anymore. Seems like the documentation most relevant now is available at https://libcxx.llvm.org/docs/DesignDocs/DebugMode.html and is currently for libc++ 12.0. That page doesn't mention debug mode not being functional. Unfortunately, XCode seems to lag behind LLVM and debug mode in XCode 11.1 still doesn't appear to be usable.

Answer (score 2):

Baum mit Augen's answer that `_LIBCPP_DEBUG_LEVEL >= 2` standard library code for lower level iterator debugging is basically unusable, appears to still be the case with the out-of-the-box Xcode 11.6. But if you're up for extra work or just want more specifics, read on...

Enabling `_LIBCPP_DEBUG_LEVEL` code is enabling [LLVM's Debug Mode](https://libcxx.llvm.org/docs/DesignDocs/DebugMode.html). According to that documentation, enabling this debug mode is done by defining the `_LIBCPP_DEBUG` to a value of 0 (that "enables most of libc++’s assertions") or 1 (that "enables 'iterator debugging' which provides additional assertions about the validity of iterators used by the program").

In XCode 11.6, I've found that adding `_LIBCPP_DEBUG=0` to a project's Debug Preprocessor Macros setting, compiles and links and indeed adds additional checks - at least checking against out of range references to `std::vector` elements via its `[]` operator. Enabling the `_LIBCPP_DEBUG_LEVEL >= 2` code is done by instead setting `_LIBCPP_DEBUG=1`. That alone however won't fully link as not all the necessary symbols are found. Specifically, the `std::__1::__libcpp_db::__insert_c(void*, std::__1::__c_node* (*)(void*, void*, std::__1::__c_node*))` symbol is reported as undefined and maybe others as well. Presumably, XCode 11.6 did not ship with this built into the standard C++ library it provides. If anybody knows better or could corroborate this, I'd appreciate hearing from them.

With the following extra work, I've been able to enable libc++'s assertions plus the additional iterator debugging capabilities:

1. Install a recent LLVM package somewhere that doesn't interfere with Xcode's included LLVM package. I installed LLVM 10.0.1 using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) and I was able to access it then under `/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/10.0.1`.
2. Have Xcode recognize the Xcode tool chain support that this new LLVM package provides. I added a symbolic link to `/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/10.0.1/Toolchains/LLVM10.0.1.xctoolchain` into Xcode's `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains` directory. I'd done that while Xcode was running and it immediately saw the new tool chain but I had to restart Xcode to get it to compile with it.
3. Under Xcode's "Xcode" -> "Toolchains" submenu, select the new tool chain. My setup showed "Xcode 11.7" and "org.llvm.10.0.1" and I selected the latter to accomplish this.
4. Add the path to the new tool chain's `usr/lib` directory to the `LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS` declaration for resulting executable Targets. I did this by adding `/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/10.0.1/Toolchains/LLVM10.0.1.xctoolchain/usr/lib` to a project's executable target "Library Search Paths" "Debug" setting.
5. Have the path to the new tool chain's include directory override the normal standard library's include directory. I haven't confirmed that this is necessary but did this by adding to my library and executable targets' `OTHER_CPLUSPLUSFLAGS` declaration the value of `-nostdinc++ -I/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/10.0.1/Toolchains/LLVM10.0.1.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1`. From within Xcode, I'd achieved that by setting the "Other C++ Flags" setting to include this value for the targets of interest. I suspect it's probably safer to make this change at the project level than target level.
6. Set the `COMPILER_INDEX_STORE_ENABLE` declaration to `NO`. This prevented "Unknown argument: '-index-store-path'" errors that stopped builds right from the beginning. I used Xcode's "Enable Index-While-Building Functionality" setting and set it to "No" for this.
7. Add `_LIBCPP_DEBUG=1` to the `GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS` declaration for the project. Did this by adding it to Xcode's "Preprocessor Macros" "Debug" setting.

For related Q&A about this, see [Is it possible to enable _LIBCPP_DEBUG2 in the current Xcode 4.6.1 toolchain on Mountain Lion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15899937/is-it-possible-to-enable-libcpp-debug2-in-the-current-xcode-4-6-1-toolchain-on).